# 404 handling - Difference between local ASP.Net (C# 4) and remote server (live)

Tags: asp.net, error-handling, http-status-code-404

I'm facing a problem:
I do want to do URL rewriting with ASP.Net

It works perfectly using my local settings, but once on the server it doesn't work as expected.

**Local**

Request to /unavailable-file.aspx gets well in the Application_Error (Global.asax.cs) and then is being redirected to /404.aspx
Request to /unavailable-random-folder or any other file gets well in the Application_Error (Global.asax.cs) and then is being redirected to /404.aspx

**Remote**
Any request to a .aspx file WILL be catched in the Application_Error
Every other request (.jpg, folder, etc...) will NOT be catched at all and thrown into the default 404 page error

My problem:

Yesterday I was installing my new website to the server and I saw that Application_BeginRequest was not even fired AT ALL on my server, when it was every time (for every file or folder requested) in my local computer (with visual studio). 
I had to create an HttpModule and now I am successfully getting the events firing... **but not for non .aspx requests.**

Everything seems to be bound on the URL : when it ends with .aspx it's correctly managed and when it's not, it's just not managed at all.

What should I do to catch every Application_BeginRequest even for non aspx page?

I have that in my web.config to try to force the 404 errors into my page:

```
<customErrors mode="On"
  defaultRedirect="404.aspx">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="404.aspx"/>
</customErrors>
```

But as I said, as long as it's not a request ending with .aspx it's not being redirected and I get the default ASP.Net 404 error.

(My host is "reliablesite" if it can help, and I have the settings of the 404 errors pointing to my 404.aspx page inside the manager (shared hosting), it does not change anything)

I wish everything would work as in local mode.

If you have any tip on how to resolve that problem let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution of this problem is given here when you have a shared environment:

1. Active the ASP.Net Integrated Pipeline in your shared environment settings (a thing that is available since IIS 7)
2. Add this to the web.config:

   ```
   <system.webServer>
   <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
     <add name="RedirectHttpModule" type="RedirectHttpModule" />
   </modules>
   </system.webServer>
   ```

Where RedirectHttpModule is a custom module handling Application_BeginRequest for example.

The "runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests" means that all managed modules will be invoked for all requests to web application.

Answer (score 1):

In the development web server every request is handled by the aspx engine, as that's all there is. In the live server different file types are handled by different engines.

To make the live server use the aspx engine for every request you have to change the configuration in IIS for the web site.

Related: [ASP.net web.config doesn't catch all 404's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6552935/asp-net-web-config-doesnt-catch-all-404s)

Comment: Thanks. That's the reason... now I'll probably have to write a module like it's being explained on this link: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/508/wildcard-script-mapping-and-iis-integrated-pipeline/